# Emulating COLSPAN with CSS without ending the previous TR

Tags: html, css, datatables, html-table

Not sure if this is possible:

I want to use [datatables](http://datatables.net/) to manipulate my table, but I want the table rows to effectively run over two lines in the table as they have a lot of embedded text:

```
+---+----+----+----+
| A | 12 | 33 | 55 | }
+---+----+----+----+ } This is one row
| A is a vowel...  | }
+---+----+----+----+
| B | 22 | 54 | 11 | }
+---+----+----+----+ } This is a second
| B is a consonant | }
+---+----+----+----+
```

(excuse my ASCII art).

Is there a good way of doing this in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatables doesn't support colspan in the body, i usually handled cases like yours by showing a button and then presenting extra data like in [this](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html) example

Comment: That looks suspiciously almost exactly what I'm looking for (except I'm perfectly happy for the table to show the data at all times.)

Now I just need to understand how it works :)